# AngularJS - How can I use the data retrieved using a Factory GET request in my controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, factory, ngresource

I created an Angular factory for fetching JSON data. I'm using `$resource` with the `get` method to retrieve this JSON object from the server. The object itself contains child objects.

I've been trying to use the data I retrieved with this factory in my controller but when I call the `$scope` variable, I get some variation of this

> Cannot read property propertyName of undefined.

I could read the property when I logged it to the console so I don't get why it just disappears. To diagnose it, I tried passing by reference another variable.

The problem is that I can find the object and its keys by logging the console. The problem is that when I try to use this data, the object keys become `undefined`. I have no idea why this happens.

```
 NewOrder.get({"id": $stateParams.loopId, "orderId": $stateParams.orderId}).$promise.then(function(order) {
    $scope.myData = order["data"];
    console.log("this is an order", order);
});
```

Here is my factory

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('NewOrder', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/loops/:id/orders/:orderId');
    });
```

I found out that if I create a new variable and set it equal to the value of `myData`, the object inside my key disappears.

This works

```
$scope.getOrder = function() {
    console.log($scope.myData);
}
=> Object {recruitingLeague: "NAHL", playerPosition: "LeftDefense", playerDOB: Object, playerHeight: Object, playerWeight: Object…}
```

Creating a new variable and passing by reference the value of the previous variable (for diagnosis purposes) doesn't.

```
$scope.newData = $scope.myData;

$scope.getOrder = function() {
    console.log($scope.newData);
}
=> undefined
```

I cannot understand why the objects I'm retrieving from my server suddenly disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service is asynchronous, so `$scope.myData` isn't there when

```
$scope.newData = $scope.myData;
```

occurs, but it is already there when

```
$scope.getOrder = function() {
    console.log($scope.myData);
}
```

is called.

Comment: So I can't use data I loaded asynchronously? Then how can I use the JSON data in my controller without it disappearing whenever I call it?

Comment: myData doesn't disappear. It is still `undefined` at the moment when you're assigning it to another variable. Use it with watcher. `$scope.$watch( 'myData', function (newVal) { if (!newVal) return; /* use $scope.myData) here */ }`. But you've already got promise chain, so you can manipulate data within `then`, it is the moment when data is already there.